# Class.getResource(className) giving me NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, cross-platform, android-resources

I have made a platform independent library that I want to use on a J2SE and Android project. Within this library I have a `Version` class that loads its version details from the manifest. On PC this works well, on Android I'm getting a `NullPointerException` and I can't figure out why.

This is my class:

```
public class Version {

    private static int APPCODE = 12354;
    private static int MAJOR;
    private static int MINOR;
    private static char RELEASE;
    private static int BUILD;
    private static int PROTOCOL;

    static {
        try {
            Class clazz = Version.class;
            String className = clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class";
            String classPath = clazz.getResource(className).toString(); //NullPointerException
            if (classPath.startsWith("jar")) {
                String manifestPath = classPath.substring(0,
                        classPath.lastIndexOf("!") + 1) + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
                Manifest manifest = new Manifest(new URL(manifestPath).openStream());
                Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                //APPCODE = Integer.parseInt(attr.getValue("APPCODE"));
                MAJOR = Integer.parseInt(attr.getValue("MAJOR"));
                MINOR = Integer.parseInt(attr.getValue("MINOR"));
                RELEASE = attr.getValue("RELEASE").charAt(0);
                BUILD = Integer.parseInt(attr.getValue("BUILD"));
                PROTOCOL = Integer.parseInt(attr.getValue("PROTOCOL"));
            } else {
                System.err.println("Couldn't find manifest, reverting to test mode");
                MAJOR = 0;
                MINOR = 0;
                RELEASE = 'n';
                BUILD = 0;
                //APPCODE = 12354;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to load manifest file. " + e);
            MAJOR = 0;
            MINOR = 0;
            RELEASE = '0';
            BUILD = 0;
            //APPCODE = 12354;
            PROTOCOL = 0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to load manifest file. " + e);
            MAJOR = 0;
            MINOR = 0;
            RELEASE = '0';
            BUILD = 0;
            //APPCODE = 12354;
            PROTOCOL = 0;
        }
    }

    public static int getProtocol() {
        return PROTOCOL;
    }

    public static int getAppCode() {
        return APPCODE;
    }

    public static int getBuildNumber() {
        return BUILD;
    }

    public static int getMajor() {
        return MAJOR;
    }

    public static int getMinor() {
        return MINOR;
    }

    public static char getRelease() {
        return RELEASE;
    }
}
```

(Please excuse the `System.err.println()` lines, those are for debugging on PC).

Why would this work fine on PC but not on Android?

Full stack trace:

```
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at com.logandam.wififileshare.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    at com.logandam.wififileshare.net.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:30)
03-12 22:13:11.687: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):    ... 15 more
```

Update: `className` = `Version.class` on both PC and Android. Using `getName()` instead of `getSimpleName()` breaks on PC and still doesn't work on Android.

Comment: he has commented the line in the code where it is thrown...

Comment: Added stack trace just in case. It's not very useful :/

Comment: Can you copy paste your stack trace plz ??

Comment: clazz.getSimpleName() returns different data in Android DVM and Java VM. Can you print out that and see what's going on?

Comment: @ChandraMohan I would print it out if I knew how to print on Android without going through `Log.d` or anything Android-specific. This class is completely platform independent and has to stay that way.

Comment: On most devices, `System.out.print`, etc, are routed to logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I don't think that this mechanism works under Android as it does in a real JVM (since dalvik is essentially not a JVM). I *think* (and I might be wrong here), that in the packaged APK, the JAR does no longer exist and therefore your path to the resource probably is wrong. The classes of your JAR are converted to the dex file format and [added to the `classes.dex` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEX_%28file_format%29). Therefore you cannot resolve a resource like `foo.bar.class` because it does not exist in the classpath.

Try to put the Version information into a text (or other resource) file and add it into the JAR and read that. The resource file should be added properly and you should be able to read it with the mechanism.

Comment: I had forgotten about the APK part completely. I just figured that since the library is in a jar file it would get packaged along inside the APK itself and everything would still work.

Comment: I added some more explanation, and an idea how to overcome it in a platform independent way.

Comment: I ended up putting a `version` file in `/res` and then using the `Property` class to neatly read it, which works perfectly on both Android and standard Java.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because the method call `clazz.getResource(className)` is returning `null` which means the resource specified by `className` cannot be found.
Put your resource file in a folder and set it as resource folder. Check [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029313/671988) for more information.
You can also check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/270398/671988) for detials about recource folders.

Comment: Except my resource is a class in a jar file. :/

Comment: There will be no problem as long as the jar file is in your classpath. Are you sure you're exporting the jar file along with your apk file?

Comment: I'm assuming so, otherwise the actual meat of the library would not be working (which it currently is).

Comment: Make sure your jar file is exported along with your apk file. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316445/how-to-use-and-package-a-jar-file-with-my-android-app

Comment: This has nothing to do with properly exporting an APK (which seems to have happened) but with the APK file-format and the differences between a JVM and dalvik.

Comment: I guess this is the same problem as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998648/use-resources-from-prebuilt-jar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep version information in manifest file and extract it in runtime. If so, welcome to Android  :-)

You have several better options rather than the one with issues you're facing.

- Use [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) with a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html):

  ```
  PackageInfo pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
          context.getPackageName(), 0);
  ```

  Then with [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) you have [`packageName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#packageName), [`versionCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode), [`versionName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionName)… Those are defined in [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).
- Store your version information in [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html), such as [`String`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), [`Integer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer)… You also need a `Context` to obtain the resources:

  ```
  String appDescription = context.getString(R.string.app_description);
  int majorBuild = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.major_build);
  // ...
  ```

I think those are better.

Comment: That's Android specific. I need platform independence. But in essence this is what I want to do.